# Nvidia 8500GT Won't display video on Asus M2A-VM

Tags: linux, graphics-card, xubuntu

I am trying to build an htpc out of old parts and everything seems fine but I want to use a
dedicated card to not use up all my onboard RAM while outputting video. My motherboard
is an Asus M2A-VM and my graphics card is a XFX nVidia 8500GT 1GB. The computer boots
normally and graphics come out of the onboard video but when I put the video card in and
set the BIOS priority to PCIEx no video comes out, onboard still works. The card is spinning
and I plugged it into another computer and it worked fine. Not sure what else to do to troubleshoot.

OS Xubuntu 13.10

`lspci` output

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (Internal gfx)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Port 2)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690 PCI to PCI Bridge (PCI Express Port 3)
00:12.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 Non-Raid-5 SATA
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI0)
00:13.1 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI1)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI2)
00:13.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI3)
00:13.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB (OHCI4)
00:13.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 USB Controller (EHCI)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 14)
00:14.1 IDE interface: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 IDE
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB600 PCI to LPC Bridge
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] HyperTransport Technology Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] K8 [Athlon64/Opteron] Miscellaneous Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS690 [Radeon X1200]
02:00.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX8112 x1 Lane PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge (rev aa)
03:00.0 Multimedia audio controller: Creative Labs SB0400 Audigy2 Value
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 01)
```

Comment: even when the bios and os havent recognized the card yet? I am using Ubuntu 13.10 XFCE (Xubuntu) and lspci does not mention nvidia or anything unrecognized

Comment: Your original revision made no mention of the operating system you were using

Answer (score 0):

This isnt really a proper solution but it worked for me hopefully someone will find a better way to do this.

I installed Windows 7 and installed the nvidia drivers with the card connected to the Mobo switched the video to the card and everything worked fine. Booted to a Xubuntu live cd and installed over everything but the windows 7 loader (possible you might be able to get rid of this too). Card now works fine in Xubuntu